# Adding main title to Bullet Graph

Tags: r, function, plot

Can you suggest a way to add a main title to that graph? The `gridBulletGraphV` function can be found [here](https://github.com/sipemu/BulletGraph/blob/master/BulletGraph.R).

```
ytd2005 <- data.frame(
  measure=c("Revenue", "Profit", "Avg Order Size", "New Customers", "Cust Satisfaction"),
  units=c("U.S. $ (1,000s)", "%", "U.S. $", "Count", "Top Rating of 5"),
  low=c(150, 20, 350, 1400, 3.5), 
  mean=c(225, 25, 500, 2000, 4.25),
  high=c(300, 30, 600, 2500, 5),
  target=c(250, 26, 550, 2100, 4.2),
  value=c(275, 22.5, 310, 1700, 4.5)
)

nticks <- c(7, 7, 7, 6, 7)
format <- c("s", "p", "s", "k", "s")

col1 <- c("#a5a7a9", "#c5c6c8", "#e6e6e7")

gridBulletGraphV(ytd2005, nticks=nticks, format=format, bcol=col1, font=11, scfont=9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by changing the function. I added a `ptitle="text"` parameter to the function and added the following code just before `for (i in 1:n) {`:

```
# Title
vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 1)
pushViewport(vp)
grid.text(label = ptitle,
          just = "centre",
          gp = gpar(fontsize=font*1.5, col="black", fontface="bold"),
          x = .5,
          y = 0.1)
upViewport()
```

You can now call the function with:

```
gridBulletGraphV(ytd2005, nticks=nticks, format=format, bcol=col1, font=11,
                 scfont=9, ptitle="Plot Title")
```

which gives the following result:
[image]

---

The revised `gridBulletGraphV` function:

```
gridBulletGraphV <- function(bgData, nticks=3, format="s", bcol=c("red", "yellow", "green"), tcol="black", vcol="black", font=25, scfont=15, ptitle="text") {
  # Data Prep
  n <- nrow(bgData)
  nam <- c("low", "mean", "high", "target", "value")
  datMat <- as.matrix(bgData[, nam])
  # Nticks/Format Prep
  if (length(nticks) == 1) {
    nticks <- rep(nticks, n)
  }
  if (length(format) == 1) {
    format <- rep(format, n)
  }
  # Layout
  hl <- rep(1, n + 2)
  hu <- c("lines", rep("null", n), "lines")
  layout <- grid.layout(4, n + 2, widths = unit(hl, hu),
                        heights = unit(c(1, 1, 5, 2), c("lines", "null", "null", "lines")))
  # Set Layout
  grid.newpage()
  pushViewport(plotViewport(c(0, 0, 0, 0), layout = layout))
  # Title
  vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 1)
  pushViewport(vp)
  grid.text(label = ptitle,
            just = "centre",
            gp = gpar(fontsize=font*1.5, col="black", fontface="bold"),
            x = .5,
            y = 0.1)
  upViewport()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    #
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 3,
                   layout.pos.col = i+1)
    pushViewport(vp)
    # Sublayout
    subLayout <- grid.layout(nrow = 1,
                             widths = unit(c(1, 2, 1), c("null", "null", "null")),
                             ncol = 3)
    pushViewport(plotViewport(c(0, 0, 0, 0), layout=subLayout))
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 1,
                   layout.pos.col = 2,
                   yscale = c(0, datMat[i, 3]))
    pushViewport(vp)
    # x-Axis Labels
    # Formatierung Label
    if (format[i] == "s") {
      brks <- labels <- round(seq(0, datMat[i, 3], length=nticks[i]), 0)
    } else if (format[i] == "p"){
      brks <- labels <- round(seq(0, datMat[i, 3], length=nticks[i]), 0)
      labels <- paste0(labels, "%")
    } else if (format[i] == "k") {
      brks <- labels <- round(seq(0, datMat[i, 3], length=nticks[i]), 0)
      labels <- format(labels, digits=10, nsmall=0, decimal.mark=".", big.mark=",")
    }
    grid.yaxis(at=brks, label=labels, gp=gpar(fontsize=scfont, col="black", fontface="bold"))
    grid.rect(y = c(0, datMat[i, 1:2]) / datMat[i, 3],
              height = unit(diff(c(0, datMat[i, 1:3])), "native"),
              x = rep(0.5, 3),
              width = 1,
              just = "bottom",
              gp = gpar(fill=bcol, col=bcol))
    grid.rect(y = c(0, datMat[i, 5]),
              height = unit(diff(c(0, datMat[i, 5])), "native"),
              x = 0.5,
              width = 0.5,
              gp = gpar(fill=vcol, col=vcol), just="bottom")
    a <- datMat[i, 1] * 0.01
    grid.rect(y = datMat[i, 4] / datMat[i, 3],
              height = unit(a, "native"),
              x = 0.5,
              width = 0.8,
              gp = gpar(fill=tcol, col=tcol), just="bottom")
    upViewport(n=3)
    # Annotation
    pushViewport(plotViewport(c(0, 0, 0, 0), layout=layout))
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 2,
                   layout.pos.col = i+1)
    pushViewport(vp)
    # Sublayout 1: Same layout as graph
    subLayout <- grid.layout(nrow = 1,
                             ncol = 3,
                             widths = unit(c(1, 2, 1), c("null", "null", "null")))
    pushViewport(plotViewport(c(0, 0, 0, 0), layout=subLayout))
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 1,
                   layout.pos.col = 2)
    pushViewport(vp)
    # Sublayout 2: two rows of text; centred middle of graph
    subLayout <- grid.layout(nrow = 3,
                             ncol = 1,
                             widths = unit(c(1, 1), c("null", "null")))
    pushViewport(plotViewport(c(0, 0, 0, 0), layout=subLayout))
    # First Text: Measure
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 2,
                   layout.pos.col = 1)
    pushViewport(vp)
    grid.text(label = bgData$measure[i],
              just = "bottom",
              gp = gpar(fontsize=font, col="black", fontface="bold"),
              x = .5,
              y = 0.1)
    upViewport()
    # Second Text: Unit
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.row = 3,
                   layout.pos.col = 1)
    pushViewport(vp)
    grid.text(label = bgData$units[i],
              just = "bottom",
              gp = gpar(fontsize=font, col="black"),
              x = .5,
              y = .5)
    upViewport(n=5)
  }
}
```